# Form input inside while loop outputting for every while instead of only a certain one

Tags: php

Im trying to make a generator where you will get something when you press a button. There are different types of generators and they are stores in sql. So i retrieve all the generators, and when i try to generate a random account from the db, it outputs the account for every generator type. I want it to only output the account on one specific generator type

```
                $generators = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM generators ORDER BY id ASC");
                while($generator = mysqli_fetch_array($generators)) { ?>

                <?php

                    $generatorname = $generator['name'];
                    if($_POST['generate']) {
                        $newaccount = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE module='$generatorname' order by RAND() LIMIT 1");
                        while($newacc = mysqli_fetch_array($newaccount)) {
                            $theaccount = $newacc['combo'];
                        }
                    }

                    $countstock = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE module='$generatorname'"));

                    if(empty($theaccount)) {
                        $theaccount = "username:password";
                    }

                ?>

                <div class="generator-box">
                    <div class="generator-stock"><?php echo $countstock; ?> in stock</div>
                    <div class="generator-title"><?php echo $generator['name']; ?></div>
                    <form method="post" src="">
                        <input type="text" class="generator-input" value="<?php echo $theaccount; ?>" readonly>
                        <input type="submit" class="generator-button" value="Generate" name="generate">
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. You say you want it to output the account on one specific generator type? Without knowing how your db model looks like, it looks like you're already doing this with this ending: WHERE module='$generatorname'. Need to know what result you are getting now vs what result you want to achieve.

Comment: No, the problem is that everything is inside the first "while" loop. So instead of outputting the account for the certain generator type, it outputs it for all of them

Comment: You only want one row for each generator type or all rows for one specific generator type?

Comment: Your first line says "SELECT * FROM generators ORDER BY id ASC" which is select all generators. So if you want to fetch data from one specific generator only you could just add WHERE someColumn = 'somevalue' before ORDER BY..

Comment: Would not that be pretty hard if i have over 50 different generator types? Because then i have to add a new while loop for each of them?

Comment: If you have 50 different generator types you would like to make it work automatically. But when I read your code you are saying: Select all generators Then Show all accounts for each generator, which will show all accounts that has a generator. If I understand you correctly you should first have a page on your website where you run the first query displaying all generators. Then when someone click on one generator, you run the second query with the specific generator that the user selected. This way you will see all generators, click on one and see all accounts for that specific generator.